# Missing values on weekends in transportation forecasting

Tags: time-series, missing-data

I am currently analyzing transport volume time series (private consumption goods) on a daily basis. I am trying to fit an auto regressive model an than also include exogenous factors (as weather, web search activity etc.).

There are two obvious seasonal patterns. During the week and during the year. However, all values at Saturday/Sunday are zero (trucks are not driving). Just ignoring weekends is not feasible, because the exogenous variables in the model occurring at the weekend influence transportation volumes during the week, e.g. web search activity on saturday influences transport volume on monday.

How can this missing values be handled appropriately?

Comment: Why not say that this model only applies to the work week (Mon-Fri) as data were not available on Sat and Sun? Why are the exogenous variables on weekends so important if there are absolutely no trucks driving on the weekends?

Comment: The idea is that e.g. the weather at the weekend or the number of clicks at certain webpages influence the number of orders at online shops. A huge fraction of total orders is placed at the weekend and than shipped during the week...

Comment: You could create a binary variable, called weekend (or whatever you want), where 1 = Sat/Sun and 0 = Mon-Fri and include that in your model.

Comment: @Matt's suggestion works well to distinguish weekends (or initial weekly segments) from other days. A subtler issue lurking here concerns the autoregressive assumption: why can we assume that the serial correlation (in the *random* components of the process) is the same between Fridays and Mondays as it is between any other two successive pairs of days? That seems to call for some exploratory data analysis and possibly some very special treatment of this problem to handle such subtle heteroscedasticity.

Comment: @whuber, agreed, with my proposed solution, we are assuming that Saturdays and Sundays have the same transport volume and that Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday ALL have the same transport volume, which is likely not the case, exploratory data analysis is a must!

Comment: @Matt I am saying something a little different. You can adjust for periodic changes in traffic volume by introducing covariates (as in your suggestion) and/or including seasonal differences. I am talking about *what's left over* after that is done, anticipating that the *residuals* from such adjustments might exhibit temporal covariances that vary throughout each "season" (week). Whether or not you include the weekend data in the series and no matter how you handle these *first order* effects, the question of this *second order* effect remains--and could be important.